# How to troubleshoot a slow re-render in Blazor; how to get the render time of each component?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, profiling, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a Blazor WebAssembly site, and the component tree has grown quite a bit.

In my Home component, a change in a child component "Foo" can happen that causes parameter property "IsChecked" to change; one of these properties is passed into a different child component "Bar".  So therefore, in my Home component, Foo's EventCallback IsCheckedChanged invokes `StateHasChanged()` so that the Home component and therefore all its children re-[render](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#lifecycle-events).

This can be slow...for me, it is taking 1-2 seconds to render and paint when even only one boolean property changes.  Supposing the user is checking and unchecking several checkboxes to trigger this rerender: this delay would be quite unwelcome on each one. (I have already ruled out that any of my other code in Home could be slowing things down.) So I gather that I have to figure out which parts of which components are slowest and perhaps have `ShouldRender` reutrn false in some cases, or otherwise do some optimization therein.  My trouble is that I don't see which components are most contributing to the render time.

So is there any way to see or write out the time it takes a Blazor component to render, as "render" is described in the [lifecycle document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#lifecycle-events)?  I assume any such render time would include the render time of all children, of course.

Is there any better way to profile Blazor WebAssembly render times?

Comment: Am not aware of any profiling services.  But, in case you haven't seen it, the following article has some interesting info on optimisation of UI rendering ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: As there's no real code to see, I would suggest that you are probably overusing `StateHasChanged` and causing a lot of unnecessary rendering.  Consider using a state service and an event/s to drive when components need to re-render.  Some example code would help.

Answer (score 3):

**(1)** Rendering from C# code to HTML's `DOM` is low-level process. Blazor debugging process only allow see value of objects/values. **No out-of-the-box for tracing Blazor redering process** (generate DOM from C# code). You can see trick

**(2)** You can use DOM change tracing:

- https://dev.to/apvarun/chrome-devtools-detecting-element-changes-gh6
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

**(3)** A trick use counter put inside per component by using a Blazor BaseComponent. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5290129/Exploring-Blazor-Component-Rendering

https://allinoneserver.azurewebsites.net/wasm.html

[image]

use `BaseCounter`

```
@inherits BaseCounter

// Markup the same as BaseCounter

@code {

    protected override string buttoncolor => "btn-success";

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Service.CounterChanged += ReRender;
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    protected void ReRender(object sender, EventArgs e) => 
                                this.InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);
}
```

and components extend from the BaseCounter, when per component called, counter will increase value, it help you see what is rendering and order of rendering process.

**(4)** Outside the question, for improving **performance**, see *Optimize rendering speed* at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-5.0#optimize-rendering-speed

Comment: Hey @Do Nhu Vy, I recognise that image and article - I was going to drop it as it only got one vote - signed The Author!

Comment: @Do Nhu Vy, I'm having trouble understanding #1.  Could you rephrase?  What is "You can see trick"?

Comment: #3 looks like a good approach for learning **how many** times a component is being rendered, but how can I learn **how much time"** it takes for each rendering (or of some group of render operations)?  If I start a Stopwatch in `protected override void OnParametersSet()` and stop it in `OnAfterRender`, I get time numbers that include render times of other components, due to asynchrony.